# Getting Word Table content via c# in connected rows

Tags: ms-word

i got an issue with a table (rows are connected/joined) and my c#-code to get the content of the cells.

I have like 12 rows, but 5 of them are connected (due to visiblity preferences, changes are not possible). In order to access the cells, i got the following code:

```
                foreach (Word.Table tbl in doc.Tables)
                {
                        // Loop through all rows in the table
                        foreach (Row row in tbl.Rows)
                        {
                            // Loop through all cells in the row
                            foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
```

The issue is now that in the "foreach (Row row in tbl.Rows)" statement, I get an exception that the enumerator cannot be accessed. I also tried a for-loop => same issue. When i manually connect the rows in the table, I get all the content.

How can I access the rows, when they are connected? I see 7 rows in the table, the debugger shows me rows.count = 12 (5 are connected). But I cannot access them in anyway.

Best regards,
Cleese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you call connected rows is merged cells, then you can't go through them column by column or row by row, you have to go through them cell by cell.

### WordVBA：

```vb
Sub tt()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rw As Row
    Dim cel As Cell
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
        'For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            'For Each cel In rw.Cells
            For Each cel In tbl.Range.Cells
                cel.Select
            Next cel
        'Next rw
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

### C#：

```cs
foreach (Word.Table tbl in doc.Tables)
                {
                    // Loop through all cells in the table
                        foreach (Cell cell in tbl.Range.Cells)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job. Now I can traverse the merged Cells and get my content.