# How can I select the first row of all tables in a Word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can you select the first row of all table in word document by using VBA

I have try these lines of code, however it results into only select the 1st row of last table

```vb
Sub SelectFirstRowOfAllTables()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim row As Row
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each row In tbl.Rows
            If row.Index = 1 Then
                row.Range.Select
            End If
        Next row
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection) can't be discontinuous, so you can't select the first row of all tables with the [Range Select method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.select). But you can still do other operations on the first row of all tables, such as changing their texts at the same time, for example:

```vb
rem Not select But collect them
Sub Collect FirstRowOfAllTables_How_can_I_select_the_first_row_of_all_tables_in_a_Word_document_using_VBA()
    
    Rem Change the text of first row of all tables to I love you
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim Row As Word.Row
    Dim rows As New VBA.Collection, cell As cell
    Dim ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
'        For Each Row In tbl.rows
'            If Row.Index = 1 Then
'                Row.Range.Select
'            End If
'        Next Row

        rows.add tbl.rows(1)
    Next tbl

    ur.StartCustomRecord "Change the text of first row of all tables to I love you and Highlight them"
    
    For Each Row In rows
        For Each cell In Row.Cells
            cell.Range.Text = "I love you"
            Rem and make them bright!!
            Row.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Next cell
    Next Row
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I have use your idea to work around. However I meet a problem with the vertical merge cell and my code results with an errror.

Comment: If you got merged cells, then you will have to go through the cells one by one and cannot iterate through them by column or row. Please refer to my answer here:
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/76238745/8249058>